# url redirect from _ to - htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have problem in my URL.

This is my code in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^music-(.*)-([0-9_]+)\.html$ /artiste.php?g=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

So some URL on Google or Bing could be showing like this `music_(.*)_([0-9_]+)\.html`
If possible I want to change `_` to `-` with htaccess.

I want any url with `_` to change to `-`, because all links work correct with `-` but in my research some URLs have `_` so I want to replace them with `-`.
example:

Error : http://www.example.com/me_like_this.html
Correct : http://www.example.com/me-like-this.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following in your `/.htaccess` file:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# Replace underscores with hyphens, set the environment variable,
# and restart the rewriting process. This essentially loops
# until all underscores have been converted to hyphens.

RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=underscore:yes,N]

# Then, once that is done, check if the underscore variable has
# been set and, if so, redirect to the new URI. This process ensures
# that the URI is rewritten in a loop *internally* so as to avoid
# multiple browser redirects.

RewriteCond %{ENV:underscore} yes
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Then add your rule afterwards:

```bash
RewriteRule ^music-(.+)-(\d+).html$ /artiste.php?g=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

If this is working for you, and you would like to make the redirects cached by browsers and search engines, change `302` to `301`.

> **Note:** In your `RewriteRule` I have changed `.*` to `.+` so it only matches **one or more** characters, instead of **zero or more** characters. Additionally, I have changed `[0-9_]+` to `\d+`, which is the shorthand equivalent without including underscores, which would be converted to hyphens anyway. If you want to include hyphens in the last capture group, then change `(\d+)` to `([\d-]+)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^music-(.*)-([0-9_]+)\.html$ /artiste.php?g=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

Please try this.

Comment: The problem with this is that the browser would have to redirect multiple times until all underscores are gone. Better to do the conversion internally.